# successful snapshot fails to load some shards, RepositoryMissingException in elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-s3, elasticsearch

I had a backup successfully complete to my s3 bucket in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "state": "SUCCESS",
  "start_time": "2014-12- 06T00:12:39.362Z",
  "start_time_in_millis": 1417824759362,
  "end_time": "2014-12-06T00:33:34.352Z",
  "end_time_in_millis": 1417826014352,
  "duration_in_millis": 1254990,
  "failures": [],
  "shards": {
    "total": 345,
    "failed": 0,
    "successful": 345
  }
}
```

But when I restore from the snapshot, I have a few failed shards, with the following message:

```
[2014-12-08 00:00:05,580][WARN ][cluster.action.shard] [Sunder] [kibana-int][4] received shard failed for [kibana-int][4],
  node[_QG8dkDaRD-H1uPL_p57lw], [P], restoring[elasticsearch:snapshot_1], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [SAuv_EU3TBGZ71NhkC7WOA], 
  reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[kibana-int][4] failed recovery]; 
  nested: IndexShardRestoreFailedException[[kibana-int][4] restore failed]; 
  nested: RepositoryMissingException[[elasticsearch] missing]; ]]
```

how I do reconcile the data, or if necessary remove the shards from my cluster to complete the recovery?